# Backbone events disappear with bootstrap tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, backbone-events

I've just found a strange beaviour with backbone views events and bootstrap tabs.

In my application, some views are attached to bootstrap tabs.

When someone click on a tab, the view attached to the tab must be (re)-rendered or just inserted in the tab (to reflect updates on the model that occurred in other views).

However, I've just realized that the events attached to the views are deleted somehow after a tab is clicked.

I've created a js fiddle demonstrating this :
http://jsfiddle.net/YbM4J/

Any ideas ?

JS:

```
window.App = {
        Views: {}
    };

    App.Views.SessionList = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'select',

        events: {
            'change': 'selectionChanged'
        },

        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'selectionChanged');
            this.render();
        },

        render: function () {
            $(this.el).append('<option value="option1">Option 1</option>');
            $(this.el).append('<option value="option2">Option 2</option>');
            return this;
        },

        selectionChanged: function (e) {
            var value = $(e.currentTarget).val();
            $("#result").html(value + ' is selected');
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var view = new App.Views.SessionList();
        var view2 = new App.Views.SessionList();
        $(".body-container #tab1").html(view.el);
        $(".body-container #tab2").html(view2.el);

        $('.tab').click(function () {
            $(".body-container #tab1").html(view.el);
            $(".body-container #tab2").html(view2.el);
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class='body-container'>
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active tab"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1"></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for rerendering tabs, don't update complete html. As in your case, view objects as available coz of closures, you can just call render() method. Here is updated fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/4FmPp/

```
$('.tab').click(function(){     
            view.render();
            view2.render();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you explain a bit more ? I don't really understand what you're saying.

Comment: The js fiddle here was just for simple example.

In my application, I have several global views. Each global view contains tabs.
Each tab contains views that have registered events.

I can only display one global view at time. Then, I think I'm forced to overwrite html, aren't I ?

Also, can you explain a bit more what you just said about closure ?

Comment: Even then you can use same method...use render of view to update html rather clearing old to replace new in tab html...closures is a concept...you anyways already using it...try internet for knowing more on closures